# Why is moving files from one harddrive to another so slow?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, 64-bit, speed, file-transfer

I use Windows Vista 64-bit and I have 6GB of RAM. Today I installed a new harddrive, and started with moving 465GB of data from my old harddrive to the new one. This process is very slow, the speed is `10,5 MB per second` and I'm not doing anything else on the computer. The estimated time is 12h for this process.

Why is it so slow?

Comment: How old is your old drive? Have you checked it with `HDTune`?

Comment: @nik: It's a Maxtor DiamondMax 11 500GB SATA 3.0Gb from 2006.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually your speed is 10.5 MB/s not 10.5 Mb/s (bytes vs bits).  Depending on the age of your system and components and the nature and quantity of files thats not a bad (or at least not uncommon) overall transfer rate.  Since you didn't give ANY specifics I'll stop here.

Comment: Additionally, copying/moving files is highly dependent on the size of the files to be moved. Usually, on large file is copied much faster than a lot of files with the same total size.

Comment: But copying a large *number* of files depends on many other factors.

Comment: You are right, it was a typo by me. But I think that is still slow. The file sizes are around 250-850MB.

Comment: I have now installed Windows 7 and moving back the same data took 2.5h, in a speed of >33MB/s so I think it is Vista that is really slow on this operation.

Comment: I moved off Vista to WIN7 as soon as the RCs came out. Have never found a reason to regret that move, and several reasons (like your examples) to recommend it.

Comment: @hotei: I haven't had a reason to upgrade or reinstall my system until now.

Comment: I now have the same problem with Windows 7, only having speed of 13-14 MB/s when moving large amout of data. I think that disks should be able to transfer data much faster. This seems to be due to fragmentation, I guess. I think that a SSD-drive would be much faster for this things.

Comment: *> thats [sic] not a bad* What‽ Ten years ago, restoring a *compressed* disk image with PowerQuest DriveImage ran at 20MB/s, and that was with my old system with old drives. How on Earth is 10MB/s considered good? It may be good for a flash-drive, but for a hard-drive, let alone the OP’s system‽ Granted, restoring a drive image was a continuous write instead of files, but even on my current (and still relatively old and slow) system and drives, I can transfer a bunch of 1GB files between two drives at a smooth 42MB/s and a heavily-fragmented 2.4GB file back at 18MB/s.

Answer (score 2):

**1** - You are restricted in this operation to the SLOWEST speed of your read/writes on either of the drives.  If drive A is 100MB/s read and 50 MB/s write and Drive B is 100 MB/s read and 10 MB/s write, you can only copy to drive B at 10 MB/s, no matter how fast drive A is.

**2** - Vista copy is slow in general.  You can use [xcopy](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) or [robocopy](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/07/robocopy-syntax-command-line-switches-and-examples/) from the command prompt which will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main complain about Vista is the slow file copy or move operations. It seems that it is the new "Remote Differential Compression" who is the culprit.

To turn it off go in Control Panel / Programs and features / Turn on or turn off Windows features and uncheck "Remote Differential Compression".

EDIT: Alternatively, you can install the [Update for Windows Vista for x64-based Systems (KB938979)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=24EAD3A0-77F6-4196-8A3F-78C1470AC18E&displaylang=en)  which Microsoft released to address the slow move/compression issue.

Comment: I don't see KB938979 addressing this specific condition (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938979). And, I don't think a `rsync` like behavior will be applicable when the target drive is empty to begin with (no previous 'version' of data). I also think this Windows 'move' will not be trying to compress before transfer.

Comment: I turned off "Remote Differential Compression" but it didn't help me today when I am transferring another 410GB of data.

Comment: You are right about Vista. I have now installed Windows 7. Moving the same 465GB data that took 12h (10.5MB/s) took 2.5h (33MB/s) with Windows 7. And it was between the same harddrives.

Comment: I have now the same problem with Windows 7. I only have a speed of 13-14MB/s. I think this is because of fragmentation. This probably goes away if I install a SSD-drive.

Answer (score 1):

Use [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) , it is a compact program designed to copy and move files at the maximum possible speed, providing the user with a lot of features

- Have a look here http://www.duxcw.com/digest/Howto/hd/cpyhd/index.html
- Very good article regarding hard-disk performance here http://www.pctechguide.com/31HardDisk_Performance.htm

Comment: I am leery of quoting from the developer's website directly in describing something.  It indicates that you haven't actually used the product...

Comment: Well I am using it for years, and I am very well satisfied. A rarely suggest a software if I don't have some personal experience or find anyone thanking that software in some other forum

Comment: It's  good you have!  Personally I just like to see what you think from your use of it instead of the text from the webpage.  When I follow a link and see the EXACT same description it gives me pause.

Comment: `TeraCopy` is good. I am not sure if it will help in this condition (have not yet figured this problem yet). But, if you can give it a try the data will be useful.

Comment: @JNK its just that i was going to type those in my words but felt lazy and copied it

Comment: +1 Thanks for the recommendation.  Windows told me it would take 13 hours to copy 4GB between two SSDs.  Teracopy took about 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to slow down any hard drive is to have too many individual streams of data too and/or from it at the same time.

I find and can prove, that copying from one drive to itself is exactly half as fast as from one drive to another, depending on the hardware obviously, equal drives and such.

This is a huge timesaver if you are extracting a lot of data from one drive to another, basically *never* extract from one drive to itself, it's twice as fast or more to extract archives to a different drive to save half the time.

Some of the newsgroup downloading programs like "grab it" have a 'folders' section where you can specify to download to one folder on one drive, and then extract to a different drive/folder, I find this saves a lot of extract time.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Windows Explorer for large copies : It's the planet's slowest copier.
Use any Explorer replacement that doesn't come up with Explorer's silly copying dialog.
My own favorite is the free [Servant Salamander 1.52](http://www.altap.cz/download.html#salrel).

If you have an antivirus, turn it off, since it will insist on checking every copied byte.

And finally: If your 12 hours estimate is based on Explorer, be advised that its estimate is normally quite wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was simply going into *Control Panel → Network and Internet → Homegroup* and I simply left the homegroup.

My speeds often started out as high as 30 MB/s and would drop to as little as 100kB/s in about 10 seconds and would actually still decrease in speed, but since leaving the homegroup my speeds are back at 20MB/s+ and holding.

Another solution is of course reinstalling Windows but let's be honest, this is not a solution and should only be done if you reach critical stress and frustration.